# Is there a way to download composer package without dev folders?

Tags: php, composer-php, production

I want to minimize traffic usage with composer packages load, so I need for production loads to only download the source/lib folders without examples/docs/readme.

I haven't found any information in the official composer documentation.

**UPD**

One of the best solution - add `.gitattributes` file into your project and add main rows from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/hannesvdvreken/89bec532ffd59637156f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really up to composer and instead a responsibility of package maintainers. You can use `--prefer-dist` to install a distribution instead of checking out the git repository as is usually done during development, but what this distribution contains is managed by the package maintainer.

If the packages you install allow for pull requests & issues, you could ask them to provide a [.gitattributes file](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) which is recognized by github when creating an archive or provide a pull request providing one. In this file you can specify which files and folders will be excluded from the archive using `export-ignore`. In any case since everything is bundled in a zip the bandwidth saved is probably negligible.

So, short answer is the only way to minimize bandwidth usage and allocated disk space for dependencies is using the `--prefer-dist` option - and omitting dev dependencies with `--no-dev` - when installing them for production.

Comment: Idea with gitattributes is great. I didn't even know that they can work like it